# Using for loop to get selected items in a listbox not working with global variable

Tags: c#, for-loop, listbox

I have two items in my listbox:

```
item1
item2
```

When i select the first item and click a button, the MessageBox displays item1. I click ok and it then displays item two as I need it to do. When debugging my application,  the global variable "pattern" is showing only the first listbox item, loops through and shows the same item again (item1). I need it to show item1 and then item2. I have removed the other code for this example, but my goal it to have this for loop capture the listbox item in a string and then call a method that will copy files to a folder based on the listbox item selection, loop through each item and copy other files for each selected item. The problem I am getting is the files would be written to the destination folder and then I would receive a files already exist error as it looped back to the first item. It should then select the second item and do the same but the copy method doesn't actually fire for the second item in the list.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            pattern = (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            MethodToCopyFiles(); // This is my method used to copy files based on the selected item in the listbox.  
            listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
            MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()); // Just here for my example, not intended for the application.
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with the following.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
    }
```

If for multiple selection, you can retrieve all selected item using code below.

```
    foreach(int i in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
    }
```